# Programmatically add UISegmentedControl in UIToolbar below UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, uitoolbar

I'm trying to get this to work on iOS 7 and 8+.

In `loadView` of the viewController, I add a `UISegmentedControl`, along with flexible spaces, as items to a `UIToolBar`. I then add the `UIToolbar` as a subview to the main view, setting the vertical position to be the height of the navigation bar.

First problem. The `UISegmentedControl` is vertically off center so the top of it, is cut off.

Second problem. Rotating to landscape messes it all up. Specifcally, the `UIToolbar` seems to move underneath the navigation bar whereas the `UISegmentedControl` doesn't.

Autoresizing issue?  I've tried various settings and can't seem to get it to center vertically within the `UIToolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your UIToolbar constraints are not set properly and also that there is no flexible space around the segmented control. Here's a link to a storyboard file I made that have proper constraints and flexible space, tested to work.

Preview:
[image]

Here's the Storyboard file: http://www.filedropper.com/main_4

Comment: Well, this might help but OP asked for programmatical implementation

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a programmatic solution though, preferably via autoresizing.